# Angular js custom domain mapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dns, routes

I want to give the users on my portal to have their domains mapped to their page and internal pages from their on.

So, the user site url http://www.username.com should map to http://example.com/userid, similarly all the links inside should also map. Like, 
http://www.user-id.com/*page1* => http://example.com/userid/*page1*
http://www.user-id.com/*section1*/*page1* => http://example.com/userid/*section1*/*page1*

Has some body done this in angular js? I am using angular 1.3 and open to move to 1.4 or 1.5

Comment: Have you thought or tried with angular-route?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example router setup with ui-router that could match what you are attempting:

```
// APPLICATION ROUTES
        // -----------------------------------
        // For any unmatched url, redirect to /app/
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login/signin");
        //
        // Set up the states
        $stateProvider.state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            templateUrl: "views/app.html",
            resolve: loadSequence('any library you want'),
            abstract: true
        }).state('app.page1', {
            url: "/page1",
            templateUrl: "views/page1.html",
            resolve: loadSequence('any library you want'),
            title: 'Dashboard'
        }).state('app.page1.section1', {
            url: '/page2',
            template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-up"></div>',
            title: 'Page 2',
     });
```